# Не работает apt update в контейнере docker

Tags: ubuntu, docker

Пишет сначала: 0% [Waiting for headerd], затем

```
 Err:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease
 Connection failed [IP: ...]
 Err:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease
 Connection failed [IP: ...]
```

на месте ... стоит ip 
Система: Ubuntu-18.04

Comment: Ну наверное что-то с DNS не так. Но вообще - docker не предполагает обновление внутри контейнера. Хочешь обновиться - пересоздай окружение заново с новым срезом версий.

Comment: необходимо внутри контейнера обновить зависимости, и устанавливать другие библиотеки

Comment: Перепиши Dockerfile и пересобери новый контейнер.